# Safari IOS Having clickable elements at top of screen doesn't work very good with landscape on Iphone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, safari, toolbar

I have this app that has a bar at the top of the page that has a bunch of clickable elements it has always been a problem since on Safari IOS when clicking high up it brings down the address bar and exits fullscreen. We solved this initially by adding some padding up top to make the clickable area larger but they seem to have increased this size on IOS 13 and adding more padding will make it look horrible. Anyone had this problem and have a workaround for it?
Some way the click area for bringing down the address bar smaller or something?

The big problem is that we need our app to stay in fullscreen so the most optimal would be to be able o decrease the clickable area for the address bar to come down or to be able to block it in landscape mode is there really no way to go around this? for instance going into twitch.com on safari and iPhone and put it in landscape you are not able to press the search icon.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, I don't think is possible to fix this as it seems to be a safari issue, if you check not event apple.com site works as expected.

The workaround I did is detecting when the app gets out of fullscreen by comparing the screen.height with the screen.availHeight and move the top bar just below the address bar and there users can click, not optimal, but works for us. :)

Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

In your CSS code try to remove every value of "REM" "VW" "VH" use only pixels "PX". that should fix the issue 100%.

Comment: This would first off be a huge refactor and also destroy a lot of the responsive design we get using EM as we are now but nice to know there is a way